# VeraCrypt-Encrypted USB Mass Storage Unusable after Formatting Error

Tags: usb, veracrypt

I recently encrypted a USB stick using a 7.5 GB stick with VeraCrypt.

After the encryption process finished, I realized I wanted to change the format of the drive to exFat instead of NTFS.

I tried decrypting the drive using VeraCrypt. Getting impatient (the drive had nothing on it, anyway), I decided to stop the process halfway and format it through File Explorer. This is where I made my mistake. I forgot to select "Quick Format", so again I got impatient. I cancelled the formatting process, but the program crashed and I heard the "USB Device Disconnected" sound.

Now the device is unrecognizable. I am greeted with the notification

> USB Device Not Recognized
> The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, so Windows does not recognize it

almost every time I insert it (it showed up as E: on one occasion but was grayed out and did not show up anywhere except File Explorer. It hasn't happened again since).
It does not show up in File Explorer, diskmgmt, nor diskpart. In device manager, it is listed as "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)". Therefore, I cannot do anything with it.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'd gladly appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: It's dead. You'll have to replace it.

Comment: How old is the stick? Have you ever tested it that it is no fake (claims to have more memory than it actually has)?

Comment: It's definitely not fake. I've used it before to store other files and it works.as advertised. As for age, I'm really not sure. It is old, and I've only begun to use it recently for small things like transferring data.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the stick is dead now. It won't show up in Ubuntu or Windows, not even as "RAW", which means I can't actually do anything with it. I guess the lesson here is to be patient with delicate operations that might damage your hardware (like that's actually going to stick, haha). Thankfully, I made sure to backup everything before it all went wrong, so at least I didn't lose anything save for the cheap usb stick.

I did consider deleting this post, but I suppose Hannu's answer here might help somebody out who might have a recoverable stick. Thanks for all the help. I appreciate the time you put into the answer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things:

1. get a Linux - e.g. an ubuntu - installation ISO  and create some kind of bootable media from it. You might even try using the troublesome stick - your problem might be solved by that step alone.

If not; then try use Linux tools to re-partition, or even erase the first megabyte of data from the USB-stick, like this:

2. boot the Linux media in "try mode"
   *) with Ubuntu running, hold CTRL and ALT, hit T - to open a terminal (bash) prompt
   *) BEFORE you insert the stick into a port, type `lsblk -p` and you will be shown the storage media available in the OS, these are usually `/dev/sd<something>`
   *) Now insert the stick into a port - make sure to find WHICH /dev/ -entry was added, by repeating `lsblk -p` - which is the one to deal with.
   *) If there is **no new device** the second time, then skip gparted below.
3. ... type `gparted &` and hit ENTER to launch one partitioning tool (there are others) - it it will likely ask for the admin/root pw;
   you should be able to use gparted to re-partition your USB-stick - unless it is broken.
4. one alternative to gparted is `gnome-disks &` - please try on your own using the GUI (too much to explain here, sorry).
5. if the either of the previous fails, even though you HAVE a /dev-name; go back to the terminal and type
   `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd<device for your usb stick> bs=1M count=1` and hit ENTER once more...
   this is an attempt to write 1MB of zeroes to the beginning of that device (so make sure to select the correct one! Pay attention to result from step 2 above ;-)

If neither of the last two works to re-vitalize your stick, or if it doesn't even show up, then the stick might well be "dead", non-working.

Comment: Unfortunately Ubuntu isn't detecting the stick. I guess it might be dead after all. Thank you for trying.